# Custom NSEntityMigrationPolicy relation

Tags: iphone, core-data, core-data-migration

I'm trying to make a database upgrade using a custom `NSEntityMigrationPolicy`. This is how my data model looks like now and what is the intended result :

```
  A <-------->> B   ( 1 A -> many B )
```

I want a new C entity which will "break" the B type objects in some subsets :

```
  A <-------->> C <------->> B  ( 1 A can have many C, each C can have many B )
```

I made a custom `NSEntityMigrationPolicy` for entity A. I created some C entities for each A in `createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:entityMapping:manager:error:` , but I'm stuck what to do with the relation between A and B.

In docs they say to use `createRelationshipsForDestinationInstance` somehow to create the new relations. I haven't found any suggestive examples however for this case. I suppose probably the A <->> C relation can be created here, but the B's may not exist yet in the destination context to create a C<-->>B relation yet. How can a migration like this be done?  Please, help :)

Thanks !

Comment: I'm in the same boat. The docs for this are terrible, no?

Comment: yeah ... I wanted to put some bounty on this, but the bounty-link doesn't appear ...

Comment: I deleted that question, it was just an idea of mine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The basic approach would be

1. Create a policy for migrating A-to-C
2. Create a policy for migrating A-to-A
3. Create a policy for migrating B-to-B

It's important to do it in the correct order.

As C does not exist in the database you have to do a little trick: The `NSMigrationManager` can store a `userInfo`. This userInfo dictionary is available throughout the whole migration process. Therefore you can store every C object you've created in A-to-C in the userInfo dict.  You need to have a unique identifier attribute on A to store this as the key and set the appropriate C object as the value. In the third migration (B-to-C) you can then access the appropriate C object and assign it to B.

**1. A-to-C: Creates the new C objects based on every existing A object.**

In `beginEntityMapping:manager:error:` create the your initial `NSMutableDictionary` and assign it to the `NSMigrationManager`'s userInfo property.

In `createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:entityMapping:manager:error:` do the following:

```
- (BOOL)createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:(NSManagedObject *)sInstance entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError **)error
{
    NSMutableDictionary *cObjects = (NSMutableDictionary *)[manager userInfo];
    NSObject *aUniqueIdentifierForEveryAObject = [sInstance valueForKey:@"aUniqueIdentifier"];

    NSManagedObject *destinationC = nil;
    if ([[cObjects allKeys] containObject:aUniqueIdentifierForEveryAObject])
    {
        newC = [userInfo objectForKey:aUniqueIdentifierForEveryAObject];
    }
    else
    {
        newC = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"C" inManagedObjectContext:[manager destinationContext]];

        // Assign instance A (sInstance) to the newC and update the userInfo
        [newC setValue:sInstance forKey:@"a"];
        [cObjects setObject:newC forKey:aUniqueIdentifierForEveryAObject];
    }

    [manager associateSourceInstance:sInstance withDestinationInstance:destinationC forEntityMapping:mapping];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)createRelationshipsForDestinationInstance:(NSManagedObject*)dInstance entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping*)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager*)manager error:(NSError**)error
{
    return YES;
}
```

**2. A-to-A: Migrates all A objects**

Here you can do some additional adjustments to A's attributes. It's important, that you create this migration whether you have attribute changes or not, as automatic migration is turned off. If you do not have any changes, you can simply create an Entity Mapping in the mapping model editor.

**3. B-to-B: Migrates all B objects and assigns new C objects**

Assign the new C objects. You cannot to this in `createRelationships...` as you need the A object and it's unique identifier to get the appropriate C from the userInfo dict.

```
- (BOOL)createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:(NSManagedObject *)sInstance entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError **)error
{
    id destinationB = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"B" inManagedObjectContext:[manager destinationContext]];
    NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = (NSMutableDictionary *)[manager userInfo];
    NSMutableDictionary *cObjects = (NSMutableDictionary *)[userInfo valueForKey:kCObjects];
    A *anA = [sInstance valueForKey:@"a"];
    NSObject *aUniqueIdentifierForA = [anA valueForKey:@"aUniqueIdentifier"];
    C *newC = [userInfo objectForKey:aUniqueIdentifierForA];
    [destinationB setValue:newC forKey:@"c"];

    // Migrate all other attributes here
    [destinationB setValue:... forKey:...];

    [manager associateSourceInstance:sInstance destinationB forEntityMapping:mapping];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)createRelationshipsForDestinationInstance:(NSManagedObject *)dInstance entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError **)error
{
    return YES;
}
```

I've not tested this but the basic approach should work.

---

**UPDATE**

There was a mistake in Step 1: A-to-C.

```
// WRONG
[cObjects setObject:newC forKey:sInstance];

// UPDATED
[newC setValue:sInstance forKey:@"a"];
[cObjects setObject:newC forKey:aUniqueIdentifierForEveryAObject];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I'll try to implement this right now. Just a short question : How can I be sure that 3. executes AFTER 1. (so I will have a populated userInfo dictionary) ? Is there a migration order in Core Data ?

Comment: You're welcome. In the Mapping Model Editor you can change the order of the Entity Mappings via Drag&Drop.

Comment: I've implemented it, but it seems it's missing something. More exactly, I can't see where the new C's are associated with the new A instance ? I think I should store the fresh instances of A with the same dictionary approach to associate them with the C's.

Comment: Yeah ... there was an error in the first step. I've updated it. Hope it's now clear what to do.

Comment: It's working :D Just a small observation, `newC` is in destination's context and `sIntance` in source's, so I've done this in A-to-A. Anyway, thanks a lot and cheers!

Comment: @FlorianMielke, you are awesome!